# PHP Google Calendar API not returning error string

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-calendar-api

I'm using a calendar which syncs both automatically and under request (if designated by user) with G!Calendar.
All works fine, except that I need to check if the calendar ID provided by the user exists.

For this I'm using:

```
$cal = "GOOGLE CALENDAR ID";
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$title = $service->calendars->get($cal);
```

If the ID exists, the script runs fine. If it doesn't, then the page craches.
How can I get the error JSON string it was supposed to return (as specified at the API resource page), so I can warn the user and block those errors from propagating?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a [try catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php) the error will be caught and you can display the message to the user.

```
function printCalendar($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $calendar = $service->calendars->get($cal);
    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! That did the job. Now I can "getCode()" it and personalize each exception and return it to the user. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to stack please remember to accept the answer if it helped you you will increase your own reputation